# WPF- DropShadowEffect not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to use BitMap Effects in my XAML, but it not's working as it says 
the member "Effect" is not accessible or recognized. I tried doing in code behind and it works but not in XAML.

Here is the XAML:

```
 <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="147,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" PreviewMouseDown="button_PreviewMouseDown"/>
        <Button.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect 
     BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="10">
            </DropShadowEffect>
        </Button.Effect>
    </Grid>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The problem is that you closed your button tag without adding the effects inside, you need to surround the `Effects` by your `Button`, meaning `<Button ... > <Button.Effect> ... </Button.Effect> </Button>`.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. I enclosed with </Button> and it's still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add an effect to a closed Button tag, make sure you remove the back slash on the opening tag

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="147,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" PreviewMouseDown="button_PreviewMouseDown">
    <Button.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect
           BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="10">
        </DropShadowEffect>
    </Button.Effect>
</Button>
```

Comment: @CookieMonster Make sure you remove the close slash on the opening button tag

Comment: It works but how do I add an event into my XAML that only fires the effect when the button is pressed?

Comment: Thats a new question